# How to estimate the gas price with ethers.js v6?

Tags: ethers.js

This question has been asked a hundred times before.
But with the change from v5 to v6 of the ethers.js library it has become unclear again how to do it.
How can I estimate the cost of a transaction like a function call or contract deployment with ethers.js v6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to figure it out too, but it's quite simple:

Ethers v5: `myContract.estimateGas.myFunction(param1, param2);`

Ethers v6: `myContract.myFunction.estimateGas(param1, param2);`

Turns out that the function name and `.estimateGas` have switched places; `.estimateGas` is now part of the function.