Cannot get Estimate Gas for ETH contract address
Is there any way to get estimate gas for Contract Address ETH?
I tried to execute eth_estimateGas methods using NowNodes and QuickNode, but both responds with:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "execution reverted"
    }
}

Any ideas?

this may help you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152267/how-to-estimate-the-gas-price-with-ethers-js-v6
